# Can i have multiple API's in the same Stage

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

Im learning AWS Application Integration and im trying to understand how the integration works in here.
My background is Mulesoft so in there I am able to have multiple api's deployed in the same Stage such as "production" for example.
And I was wondering if I can have multiple api's in the same stage and control them all at once in the stage.
Also if you could make me understand if in AWS we can call an api that goes to another api does the logic and comes back to another different api. Im finding hard to see the strong points on AWS API integration.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can have multiple APIs in the same stage.
You can use the AWS API Gateway service. Once the Resource and method is created you can start deploying the API, While deploying the API, The console will ask for the stage in which you want to deploy. [image: Like this!]
you can have a look at the documentation [Deploy REST API using AWS API Gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-deploy-api-with-console.html)

You can make use of lambda for the second part of your question. AWS Step function is useful when it comes to the orchestration of services. Have a look at documentation [Here!](https://aws.amazon.com/step-functions/)

Comment: Well I tried that, I created an API andcreated a stage inside of it. THen went back and created another API and when deploy it pops up that window but it doesnt appear the stage that i have created in the other API. Can this be about permissions or something?

Comment: Maybe you are messing up with some steps, if you see the documentation, the 6th step clearly mentions that you can choose an existing stage. provide more information to debug the issue.

Comment: Well I can use an existing stage inside the api, if i  create the stage "dev" in api x and create another stage inside the api x again it will appear the stage "dev" but doesnt appear on apy y